# Firebase Admin SDK: NoSuchMethodError for setCredential()

Tags: java, maven, firebase, firebase-admin

My application uses the Firebase Admin SDK for Java (recently upgraded from the Firebase Server SDK). It has worked correctly while testing on the local environment, however after deploying it to Google App Engine from Eclipse, the logs are showing this error:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setCredential(Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseCredential;)Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder;
```

Can anyone advise? I have checked `pom.xml` on the server and I can see that the firebase-admin SDK dependency was uploaded successfully:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to upgrade Firebase version to 4.1.0 or later. `com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setCredential()` has been introduced since version 4.1.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using v5.2.0. Updated the original question with this detail

Comment: I think your application refers to an old version jar (cache). Try to run `mvn clean`.

Comment: It looks like the app uploaded to App Engine still has the old version of the jar. Something like `mvn clean appengine:deploy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Tomcat 8.0 on a dev machine (Windows 10). 
I had just migrated firebase-admin from 4.1.7 version to the latest one (6.11.0), so there was somewhere an old firebase-admin-4.1.7.jar.

Hence that's what I did to fix:

- find and delete any copy of firebase-admin-4.1.7.jar from my dev machine (check lib/ folders)
- remove webapp from Tomcat Server
- Maven Update
- Project Clean